# Dropping semi-dupliacted rows in pandas according to specific column value

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with duplicated rows except one column value, I want to drop the row with a value of "None" if the id is the same (not all the rows are duplicated)

```
       a    b    
1      1    None
2      1    7
3      2    2
4      3    4
```

I need to drop the first row with the duplicated (1) and the value of b is None.

Comment: I understand that you want to drop the rows where column 'a' has the same value as the index. Is this correct? Your phrasing is a little confusing. Your title states that you want to drop duplicated rows, but your example dataframe above does not have any duplicated row. Please consider clarifying your question.

Comment: That's why I used (semi-duplicated) rows, they are the same except one column value. and for your question no, the value of column "a" not the same value of the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `duplicated` and also search for `None`. That will return the row you want to drop, so use `~` to get the inverse dataframe (so everything but the row you want to drop) to return the expected result. EDIT: Passing `keep=False` will return all duplicates, so order doesn't matter.

```
df[~((df['b'].isnull()) & (df.duplicated('a', keep=False)))] #if None is Null value
```

OR

```
df[~((df['b'] == 'None') & (df.duplicated('a', keep=False)))] if 'None' is string
```